# How do I fix or debug "Error: Android Packager: [app] Cannot create new key or keystore" in IntelliJ

Tags: android, intellij-idea

I have an Android project with `.iml` files that I have generated myself. I am specifying my own keystore:

```
 <option name="CUSTOM_DEBUG_KEYSTORE_PATH" value="file://$MODULE_DIR$/debug.keystore" />
```

and the `debug.keystore` is a shared keystore file that comes from version control: it was not generated on my machine.

When I try to build the APK using IntelliJ 12.1.4 on Ubuntu 12.04, I get the following error:

```
Error: Android Packager: [app] Cannot create new key or keystore
```

Any idea what is causing this error or where I can look to debug it?

Answer (score 3):

In Ubuntu, i did solved this problem by owning the folder :
**home/user_name/.android** :

```
sudo chown -R user_name:user_group /home/user_name/.android
```

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure the keystore file is owned by you. I had this issue a while ago and I found out that my keystore directory/file was owned by root.

Answer (score 0):

For Intellij to use your custom keystore, your keystore must be configured with the [standard debug key store alias/keys](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html#debugmode):

```
Keystore name: "debug.keystore"
Keystore password: "android"
Key alias: "androiddebugkey"
Key password: "android"
```